# Cointegration inference that allows for including stationary variables

Tags: time-series, cointegration

There is an I(0) variable in my defined model. I came across this paper by Rahbek & Mosconi (1999) which allows for inclusion and they tell us how the rank changes when we include I(0) variables in our analysis.

In my knowledge, I did not find any package which models this. Does anyone know anything about this that can help me?

<sup>Rahbek, Anders, and Rocco Mosconi. ["Cointegration rank inference with stationary regressors in VAR models."](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/1368-423X.00021/full) *The Econometrics Journal 2.1* (1999): 76-91.</sup>

Comment: Could you give a full citation for Rahbek (1999)?

Comment: @RichardHardy Rahbek, Anders, and Rocco Mosconi. "Cointegration rank inference with stationary regressors in VAR models." The Econometrics Journal 2.1 (1999): 76-91.